# password protected installer .net

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, windows-services, installation

I am working with the solution which has WPF window, which is working with SQLLite database and Windows Service, which uses the database data. Also, WPF window has used an installer and uninstaller for windows service.

The main idea of this program is to control access/deny to all programs. I have all scripts finished, but I have to create installer and uninstaller for this solution, and uninstaller has to be protected by the password ( this program has the same idea as parent control programs, so some users don`t have to be able to use/delete the program) Maybe there is some other solution to protect it without creating installer and uninstaller?

I had the idea that use was able to delete all files, but windows service will be still working because it was installed by the WPF window before. It seems to be a good solution, but in this case, SQLLite database will be removed.

Comment: Typically who is allowed to remove or delete (or add or create...) things is governed by the access control features of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Have the windows service and/or the wpf app create/copy the database in runtime and put it in another directory (e.g. `LocalAppData`). This way, when the user decides to uninstall the programs, their local database will not be removed from their machines.

Comment: THank you for your answer. So I will send the client a folder with my solution and when he will install the windows service using wpf GUI , the sqllite database will be removed to localAppData. It seems to me to be a very good idea. The client will use wpf GUI app as an installer for windows service and as a picker for programs deny/access. If service is installed the client or his children can delete the folder I sent to him, but service will be still working. if he want to control the program and service, he will have to download GUI once more. Am I right? Thank you!

Comment: If you mean "...moved to localAppData" then yes you got the idea right.